# ¿Por qué MongoDB lanza el error "SyntaxError: missing : after property id" al hacer un update?

Tags: mongodb

Tengo en una coleccion documentos como el siguiente:

```
{
  id: ObjectId(13796844978),
  n_empleado:1,
  geometry:{
     coordinates:[0,1]
  }
}
```

Estoy intentando actualizar el array coordinates y no encuento la manera. Estoy intentando, por ejemplo, con la siguiente consulta añadir el valor 8 al array:

```
db.collection.update({n_empleado:1},{$push:{geometry.coordinates:8}})
```

Pero salta un error. El error que me da la consola de Mongo es:

> ```
> E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):1:50
> ```

Tambien estoy buscando la manera de sustituir el array por otro:

```
db.collection.update({n_empleado:1},{$set:{geometry.coordinates:[4,5]}})
```

y también da error. El error que da en este caso es:

> ```
> E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):1:49
> ```

¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo conseguirlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dado que tu query incluye documentos anidados, debes utilizar comillas para referenciarlos correctamente.

De este modo, en lugar de decir:

```
db.collection.update({n_empleado:1},{$push:{geometry.coordinates:8}})
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Debes decir:

```
db.collection.update({n_empleado:1},{$push:{"geometry.coordinates":8}})
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Referencia: [query in mongo Shell gives SyntaxError: missing : after property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38930334/1983854)